# Can't animate a C3 chart with different datasets using scrollytelling (Scrolltop)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scroll, scrolltop, c3.js

I've created a C3.js bar chart that I'm trying to animate as it scrolls down an HTML page. Essentially, I want it to change data sets as it gets to a certain point in the page.

This is my the script I've placed at the bottom of my HTML pages:

```
$(window).scroll(animateChart);

// Find scroll percentage on scroll (using cross-browser properties),
// and offset dash same amount as percentage scrolled down the page


function animateChart() {

  //  get the percentage scolled down the page, log thes values to see whats going on
  let scrollpercent = (document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);

  console.log(scrollpercent);


  if (scrollpercent < 0.5593009360685123) {
    getTotalCount()
  };

  if (scrollpercent > 0.5593009360685123) {
    getPerCapita()
  };

  function getTotalCount() {
    $("#bar_chart").load({
      columns: [
        ['data', 5120, 363, 1908, 445, 87, 5752, 1020, 4, 1187, 3145, 2445, 253],
      ],
      unload: ['data2', 201.9, 72.6, 187.3, 26.7, 16.9, 393.7, 100.2, 0.3, 171.5, 277.7, 89.3, 37.2],
    });
  };

  function getPerCapita() {
    $("#bar_chart").load({
      columns: [
        ['data2', 201.9, 72.6, 187.3, 26.7, 16.9, 393.7, 100.2, 0.3, 171.5, 277.7, 89.3, 37.2],
      ],
      unload: ['data', 5120, 363, 1908, 445, 87, 5752, 1020, 4, 1187, 3145, 2445, 253],
    });
  };

};
```

And this is my bar chart as follows:

```
var bar_chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#bar_chart',
  size: {
    height: 600,
  },
  interaction: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Total count vs per capita?'
  },
  bar: {
    width: {
      ratio: 0.75,
    },
    label: {
      format: function(value) {
        return d3.format(",d")(value) + "%";
      }
    }
  },
  axis: {
    rotated: true,
    x: {
      type: 'category',
      categories: ['Bedfordshire, Hertfordshire & Cambridgeshire Constabularies', 'Cumbria Constabulary', 'Derbyshire Constabulary', 'Devon & Cornwall Police',
      'Dyfed Powys Police', 'Lancashire Constabulary', 'Leicestershire Police', 'Norfolk & Suffolk Constabularies', '"Northamptonshire Police', 'Surrey Police', 'West Midlands Police',
      'Wiltshire Police'],
      tick: {
        show: false
      }
    },
  },
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data', 5120, 363, 1908, 445, 87, 5752, 1020, 4, 1187, 3145, 2445, 253],
    ],
    type: 'bar',
    labels: true,
    colors: {
      // 'average wage': '#DCEDC8'
      'data': '#42B3D5'
    },
  },
  grid: {
    y: {
      show: true,
      lines: [{
        value: 1187,
        text: 'Median',
        class: 'annotation-line',
        position: 'start'
      }]
    }
  },
  legend: {
    show: false,
  },
});
```

My code is definetly running because the console.log() function I've scripted to figured out at what point in the page I'm in is active in the consolde. My C3 chart also works when I animated it only using the timeout() function. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

'load' is a c3 function. Reference the variable you make from the c3 instance rather than the element id through jquery

```
bar_chart.load
```

not

```
$("#bar_chart").load
```